# How to avoid silent swallowing of exceptions from async methods inside hangfire jobs?

Tags: async-await, hangfire

Since 1.6 Hangfire [supports using the `await` keyword in background tasks](https://www.hangfire.io/blog/2016/07/16/hangfire-1.6.0.html#async-methods-for-background-jobs),

However, it is not real asynchronous support, and it ignores any exceptions thrown by asynchronous methods, which leads to failing jobs being treated as successful.

E.g. if I have a hangfire job that invokes a method like `MyJobMethod()`:

```
public async Task MyJobMethod()
{
    var foo = await this.bar.SomeMethodThatMayThrowAsync();
}
```

Even if `SomeMethodThatMayThrowAsync()` throws an exception, the Hangfire job succeeds.

How do I make sure that exceptions are not swallowed when using asynchronous methods inside Hangfire jobs?

Should I be using `.Wait()`, and if so, what are the pitfalls to look out for?

Comment: Are those async void methods? As the linked doc explicitly states those aren't supported. They swallow the exceptions as well.

Comment: @Nkosi No, this happens inside `async Task` job methods.

Comment: I'm running a lot of async jobs, and have never seen the exceptions from async method calls being ignored. Can you provide a short self-contained example of such behavior?

Comment: @AlexSkalozub Thanks for your comment. I cannot reproduce this behaviour in a simple test case. I'll need to revisit my code (which I have since rewritten to be synchronous) to double check.